# Renaming files after a specific character

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, batch-rename

Was hoping to get some help here. I have a bunch of files that are monitored and the ending facility removed, files look as follows:

LastName, FirstName_DOS-Facility.pdf

I currently run the below:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B "*.pdf"') do (
    ECHO move "%%a-%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
)
```

And it creates LastName, FirstName_DOS.pdf

The issue I'm running into is multiple files with the same name, my batch file just replaces the older file with the newer. Is there a way to append a _1.pdf _2.pdf _3.pdf , etc if needed? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a commented batch code suitable for your task requirements.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ('dir "*-*.pdf" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    if not exist "%%a%%~xb" (
        ren "%%a-%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
    ) else (
        call :GetNextAppendix "%%a" "%%~xb"
        ren "%%a-%%b" "%%a!NextAppendix!%%~xb"
    )
)

endlocal
goto :EOF

rem This subroutine inserts between file name passed as first argument
rem and file extension passed as second argument an underscore and an
rem incrementing number in range 1 to 50000 and checks if a file with
rem this name already exists. If there is no file with current number
rem in file name, this number with the preceding underscore is assigned
rem to an environment variable used in parent process routine to rename
rem the file.

:GetNextAppendix
for /L %%I in (1,1,50000) do (
    if not exist "%~1_%%I%~2" (
        set "NextAppendix=_%%I"
        goto :EOF
    )
)

rem Windows command interpreter should never reach this part of the code.
rem But in case of this really happens, simply clear the appendix variable
rem which results in a failed renaming of file in parent process loop 
rem above with output of an error message because of file already existing.

set "NextAppendix="
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And see also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2^>nul` which is `2>nul` with redirection operator `>` escaped with `^` to be applied on execution of command **DIR** and not being interpreted as redirection operation for command **FOR** at an invalid position within the command line.

This redirects the error message output by **DIR** on no file matching the wildcard pattern `*-*.pdf` from **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Comment: This got it done! Thank you so much!! Now if I can find a way to read the DOS in the file name, create a folder (or just move file if it exists)and move the file in there, my life will be easier!

Answer (score 0):

Save the script to *test.bat* and run from open Cmd Prompt. Replace *dir* value with your path. Let me know if any errors.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dir=C:\My_Files"
pushd "%dir%"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B "*.pdf" 2^>nul') do (
    call :rename %%a %%b )
popd
exit /b

:rename
set "i="
:loop
if exist "%1!i!%~x2" (set /a "i+=1" & goto :loop)
ren "%1-%2" "%1!i!%~x2"
exit /b
```

Comment: Pls Upvote and Accept an answer that fits your needs by using buttons to the left of Answer Box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This script is just giving "The system cannot find the file specified" error, twice. With two .pdf in the folder.

Comment: Updated the script. Did you replace the _dir_ path with your own?